# Need to write a JSON query on MarkLogic

Tags: json, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using `MarkLogic 8` and using the Java Api to write and read documents.

I am storing documents as `json` and the `json` contains a node that is a time stamp in milliseconds( java long value). I need to query documents based on this timestamp.

I.e., say for a given range **longvalue1** to **longvalue2**. How do I do that?

I have seen examples like -

```
 { query { "key": "value"} }
```

But can I use **> or <** in the query there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read through the Search Developer's guide section on [Query By Example](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe#chapter).  You can create a range index of type long on your timestamp property then use [Comparison Operators](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe#id_34290) on [Range Query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe#id_41076).

Comment: Thank you Sam, found what I was looking for.